# Reference to multipile versions of same dependency in modular application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've designed a modular system based on `ASP.Net MVC`. Every module is an independent `ASP.Net Mvc` application which can be run alone. But if I load them into my core application the controllers and views and ... will merged to the my core app.

The loading module mechanism is based on loading assembly to my current app domain in core, and registering the controllers and other services in my `IoC`'s container. Also I load the referenced dependencies by the module one-by-one into current app domain, so it runs perfect.

**BUT, my problem** is that if two different versions of the same third-party assembly be referenced by two different module it causes error which it says cannot one or more dependencies of the assembly exception and the app stops!

**Question:** what is/are the general solution or approach to dealing with above problem?

Comment: What's the exception exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strong naming is the general solution for your problem. Effectively when using a strong name, 2 different version of the "same" assembly are treated as two different assemblies.

In your modules,

1. in Solution Explorer, right mouse click on the reference that is causing the issue,
2. choose properties,
3. ensure they are strong named,
4. if so then select the `SpecificVersion` option and set it to `true`

This will ensure that given module will only use a given version of the 3rd party dependency.

[image]

Comment: hmm... It likes to work... let me check it :)